# Read DynamicJsonArray with razor (mvc4 Umbraco)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm reading Json from https://demoapi.thismoment.com/v4.1/api/content

Reading it as stream:

```
Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(url);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
String request = reader.ReadToEnd();
var requestJson = @Json.Decode(request);
```

and getting list of results

```
var resultsList = new List<dynamic>(requestJson.results);
```

When trying to read next level

```
var resultsList = new List<dynamic>(requestJson.results.media);
```

I'm getting this error:  **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.**

When I iterate through the list

```
foreach (var item in resultsList)
{
<a>@item.media</a>
}
```

each media item is **System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonArray**.

I need to read this array, so I can get url and size of each image.

The above json url is public.
I'm doing it in Umbraco 7, which uses razor code (aps mvc 4).

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method to do it:

```
private static List<T> GetcollectionFromJason<T>(string jasonUrl) where T : new()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(jasonUrl);
            List<T> retCollection = new List<T>();
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                        string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                        retCollection = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(jsonString);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException exp)
            {
                WebResponse errorResponse = exp.Response;
                using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                        String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            return retCollection;
        }
```

And to call it you can have this:

```
List<YourModel> technicalIssues = GetcollectionFromJason<YourModel>(YourJsonUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with `JavaScriptSerializer`. Right now, I don't know how to tell Umbraco's `@Json.Decode()` to return an own type that inherits `DynamicObject` and overrides `TryGetProperty()`. So I'm ending up using the Serializer as you show.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)